# How to lookup multiple highest values from one data reference?

Tags: excel-formula

I got stuck with my logic excel formula that returns the highest values with multiple ID's from 1 data history reference.

It is simple of course, but I met a dead end.

So please help to returns the highest ID at [MAX_PTS_ID] from the refence on the right.

[image]

Comment: Try using this [tool](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to show your sample data, or provide a screenshot of your sample data and the expected outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, using INDEX & MATCH:

```
=MAX(INDEX($F$2:$F$7,MATCH(A2,$E$2:$E$7,0)),INDEX($F$2:$F$7,MATCH(B2,$E$2:$E$7,0)))
```

[image]

**Edit** - match five IDs (or any given number - adjust ranges as necessary):

```
=INDEX($H$2:$H$11,MATCH(MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($H$2:$H$11,A2:E2,0)),$I$2:$I$11)),$I$2:$I$11,0))
```

Note that this is an array formula so it needs to be entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Result:

[image]

Comment: many thanks, but I try your formula, it just need little fixing I think,

OLD_ID NEW_ID MAX_PTS_ID
111            999       999           (it should be 111 cause it has 7 pts than 999)
222            888       888
333            777       777           (it should be 333 cause it has 9 pts than 777)

ID PTS
111 7
222 2
333 9
999 4
888 5
777 6

your time is a big help for me, pls help.

Comment: Sure, see my edited answer, hope it helps. I'm checking now if there is a shorter version of this formula...

Comment: Here's an alternative Array formula (enter with Ctrl+Shift+Enter): `=INDEX($E$2:$E$7,MATCH(MAX(MAX($F$2:$F$7*($E$2:$E$7=A2)),MAX($F$2:$F$7*($E$2:$E$7=B2))),$F$2:$F$7,0))` However, I suspect that formula in my edited post will be faster.

Comment: thank you, you're brilliant.
Now, if I have 5 different ID, should I repeat the same formula? or any magic for this kind :D please help

Comment: This request forced me to rethink the whole formula and I just updated my answer with even better approach... check it out (edited post)! P.S. Don't forget to accept/upvote my answer if you think it's useful. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

So, depending which you want to use as the source try:

[image]